# Proper way to add padding to byte slice in golang?

Tags: encryption, go, block-cipher

I'm trying to encrypt some data in go but it's hardly ever the correct `cipher.BlockSize`.

Is there a "built-in" way to add padding or should I be using a function to add it manually?

This is my solution now:

```
// encrypt() encrypts the message, but sometimes the 
// message isn't the proper length, so we add padding.
func encrypt(msg []byte, key []byte) []byte {        
  cipher, err := aes.NewCipher(key)                  
  if err != nil {                                    
    log.Fatal(err)                                   
  }                                                  

  if len(msg) < cipher.BlockSize() {                 
    var endLength = cipher.BlockSize() - len(msg)    
    ending := make([]byte, endLength, endLength)     
    msg = append(msg[:], ending[:]...)               
    cipher.Encrypt(msg, msg)                         
  } else {                                           
    var endLength = len(msg) % cipher.BlockSize()    
    ending := make([]byte, endLength, endLength)     
    msg = append(msg[:], ending[:]...)               
    cipher.Encrypt(msg, msg)                         
  }                                                  
  return msg                                         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Package cipher](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/) it appears like you may have to add the padding yourself, see [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Essentially add the required padding bytes with the value of each byte the number of padding byte added.

Note that you need to add padding consistently and that means that if the data to be encrypted is an exact multiple of the block size an entire block of padding must be added since there is no way to know from the data if padding has been added or not, it is a common mistake to try to out-smart this. Consider if the last byte is 0x00, is that padding or data?

Comment: Here is a good implementation of that: https://github.com/go-web/tokenizer/blob/master/pkcs7.go (block size for AES is 16 byte)

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution

```
// padOrTrim returns (size) bytes from input (bb)
// Short bb gets zeros prefixed, Long bb gets left/MSB bits trimmed
func padOrTrim(bb []byte, size int) []byte {
    l := len(bb)
    if l == size {
        return bb
    }
    if l > size {
        return bb[l-size:]
    }
    tmp := make([]byte, size)
    copy(tmp[size-l:], bb)
    return tmp
}
```

Comment: It really is best to use accepted methods and [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) it a generally accepted and common method of padding symetric encryption.

Comment: @zaph good to know, i was using this for non-cryptographic applications